# Your function should not mutate the input array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, bubble-sort

I was trying to solve a coding challenge on Codewars. My solution passed all the tests except for one which says the following:

should be pure, i.e. not mutate the original array
Your function should not mutate the input array: expected `[ 2, 5, 5, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ]` to deeply equal `[ 2, 5, 3, 7, 1, 10, 4, 6, 8, 9 ]`.

Here is my solution to the challenge called: Bubblesort Once

```js
function bubblesortOnce(a) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
      newArr[i] = a[i + 1];
      a[i + 1] = a[i];
    } else {
      newArr[i] = a[i];
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `a[i + 1] = a[i]` modifies the original array.

Comment: You could put `a = [...a]` at the beginning of the function to make a copy of it.

Comment: The thing I want to know is why this was an issue at the beginning. Was this just a requirement from the challenge itself or something mandatory in general?

Comment: It's just a requirement of the challenge.

Comment: For example, the built-in JavaScript `sort()` method modifies the array in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your function should not mutate the input array

The **Input array** is the array passed into your function.
**Mutation** is another word for changing the value of something.

To stop changing the input array we can use the [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (...) to copy each element of the input array into a new array, and then change that new array instead:

The below snippet utilises a new "passedArray" input which is then *copied* with the spread operator into a new array:

```js
function bubblesortOnce(passedArray) {
  let a = [...passedArray]; //copy the array
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
      newArr[i] = a[i + 1];
      a[i + 1] = a[i];
    } else {
      newArr[i] = a[i];
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
```